# Makefile trace target not found but exists and runs it

Tags: makefile

I created a makefile to build some code and when adding --trace option to debug/make sure everything is good, I noticed that there is a print saying some target is not found, even if it is there and it executes it. So I created a more simple example to point this and ask around why this is happening.

My makefile:

```
APP_NAME = apl
ODIR = obj

all: $(APP_NAME)

$(ODIR):
    @mkdir -p $(ODIR)

$(APP_NAME): $(ODIR)
```

If I execute it with `make all` it creates the obj folder.
If I add the `--trace` option at the end it says that the `obj` target does not exist and it creates the folder:

```
$ make all --trace 
makefile:7: target 'obj' does not exist
mkdir -p obj
$ ll
drwxrwxr-x.  2 user user  4096 Aug 17 10:44  obj
```

I have a linux machine with fedora installed. Can anyone help me understand why that message?

Comment: Hint: use order-only dependencies for directories: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trace message...

```
makefile:7: target 'obj' does not exist
```

is simply informational.  It's telling you *why* the `mkdir -p obj` was executed.  If you specify some dependency for `$(OBJ)` and arrange for that dependency to be newer than `$(OBJ)` then the message would be something like...

```
makefile:7: update target 'obj' due to: <dependency name>
```

Comment: yes, it seems it is just informational... I started to worry. Thanks